# How can i see my database file in android studio when connect with a real device?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio, file-io

My data folder is empty in device monitor. When i put a db into internal memory i can see that in sdcard0, i can access that file but can’t write more than one row.    ~ Am new in android ~. This is my code,

```
 public static final String Query="CREATE TABLE "+UserConstruct.newUserinfo.TableName+" ("+UserConstruct.newUserinfo.UserName+" TEXT, "+UserConstruct.newUserinfo.Password+" TEXT,"+
                UserConstruct.newUserinfo.FName+" TEXT, "+UserConstruct.newUserinfo.LName+" TEXT,"+UserConstruct.newUserinfo.ACode+" TEXT,"+UserConstruct.newUserinfo.AEmail+" TEXT);";



   public DatabaseHelper(Context context)
    {
        super(context,DatabaseName,null,DatabaseVersion);
        Log.e("Database operation","created or opened");

    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
    {
        db.execSQL(Query);
        Log.e("Created","Table Created");
        File f=new File("/data/data/com.example.future.buildingmonitoringsystem/databases/ptl2_DB.db");
        FileInputStream fis=null;
        FileOutputStream fos=null;

        try
        {
            fis=new FileInputStream(f);
            fos=new FileOutputStream("/mnt/sdcard/ptl2_DB.db");
            while(true)
            {
                int i=fis.read();
                if(i!=-1)
                {fos.write(i);}
                else
                {break;}
            }
            fos.flush();


code for insertion in main class:
   String UserName="admin"
   Password = "password";
         String FName="abc";
         String LName="abc";
         String ACode="1234";
         String AEmail="sjn@gmail.com";
         String TableName="htl_portal_user";

        dbhelper=new DatabaseHelper(context);
        sqlitedatabase=dbhelper.getWritableDatabase();
        dbhelper.insert( UserName,Password,FName,LName,ACode,AEmail,sqlitedatabase);
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Data inserted",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        dbhelper.close();
```

Comment: Cant write more than 1 row? What is your approach? Where is the code that you attempted to execute? This will be downvoted soon.

Comment: Is your device rooted ?

Comment: device not rooted.

Comment: Please post your code where you are inserting data in your DB

Answer (score 0):

You can not see database if you are using Real Device. If you want to see the database you have to export the database.

Code for export database is here with :

```
btnexport.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                File f=new File("/data/data/YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME/databases/YOUR_DATABASE_NAME");
                FileInputStream fis=null;
                FileOutputStream fos=null;

                try
                {
                    fis=new FileInputStream(f);
                    fos=new FileOutputStream("/mnt/sdcard/DATABAASE_.db");
                    while(true)
                    {
                        int i=fis.read();
                        if(i!=-1)
                        {fos.write(i);}
                        else
                        {break;}
                    }
                    fos.flush();
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Database Export Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "DB dump ERROR", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Done this and now i can see the db in my sdcard. I can write one row and also i can access it. And the problem is can't access the db after the insertion of second row. When i tried for that app hanged and get stop.

Comment: Code is added in my question.

Answer (score 0):

Currently it is not possible to see your database file in Android Studio. You will have to follow the following steps :

1.Create your Sqlite database file in your app programatically

2.Export it to your computer - it will have the file extension .sqlite

3.To open this file you need a mozilla plugin - SQLite Manager - Add this plugin to your mozilla browser

4.Now, you can open your exported file in SQlite Manager - You can even perform many database functionalities in the SQLite manager.

To export your db file in your android device follow the following code:

```
export.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                File f=new File("/data/data/YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME/databases/YOUR_DATABASE_NAME");
                FileInputStream fis=null;
                FileOutputStream fos=null;

                try
                {
                    fis=new FileInputStream(f);
                    fos=new FileOutputStream("/mnt/sdcard/DATABAASE_.db");
                    while(true)
                    {
                        int i=fis.read();
                        if(i!=-1)
                        {fos.write(i);}
                        else
                        {break;}
                    }
                    fos.flush();
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Database Export Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "DB dump ERROR", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: I have done this and the db file i can see in my sdcard. And the problem is,  when i tried to access the data after the insertion of second row the app is hanged and then closed. [if there is only one row i can access it.]